# Error when linking react-native-splash-screen

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I install [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) package by running this command

```
yarn add react-native-splash-screen@3.0.6
```

It was installed successfully, But when I linking it by run this command

```
react-native link react-native-splash-screen
```

I got an error, and this is the output

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in REACT_NATIVE_PROJECT\node_modules (339ms)
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-splash-screen ios dependency
rnpm-install info Platform 'ios' module react-native-splash-screen has been successfully linked
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-splash-screen android dependency
rnpm-install ERR! Something went wrong while linking. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'REACT_NATIVE_PROJECT\android\app\src\main\java\DOMAIN_NAME\COMPANY_NAME\MainApplication.java'
Please file an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues

ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'REACT_NATIVE_PROJECT\android\app\src\main\java\DOMAIN_NAME\COMPANY_NAME\MainApplication.java'
```

Comment: Try the manual linking if the automatic linking doesn't work, seems like there are some changes done to your file paths